# Incomplete Intellisense in Razor View

Tags: html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I can't figure out why some intellisense are missing in my .cshtml files.

**Options I have tried:**

- Deleted the hidden .vs folder
- Deleted the bin and obj folder (I knew this wasn't the cause but wanted to be sure with my trobleshooting)
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Restarted my machine.

All efforts turned out to be odd.

To be specific, the "asp-" element isn't showing in the intellisense and even if I use it, it is not responding. For example:

`<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">`

See screenshot below

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have _ViewImports.cshtml file? You are supposed to add the name space `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` explicitly in the file like `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Comment: Thanks Sai Gummaluri, I just checked through all and found that the _ViewImports.cshtml file was in the Shared folder instead for Views folder. But just for me to come back on stackoverflow to give a feedback, then I found your comment. 
Thanks for your time